# Alpha on Katz Backoff using Simple Good-Turing

Tags: predictive-models, model, natural-language, language-models

I'm building an n-gram language model to predict the next word, I've implemented a simple Good-Turing smoothing on all my probabilities and have calculated the P0(mass probability of unseen event).

I want to know if the Alpha for the lower order Ngrams when using Katz Backoff is exactly this P0 or I should do some other calculation?